# Receiving "undefinedError $" and code doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT**: I have included the full HTML with style and scripts as it appears in my html file.

I want to have a portion of my article to collapse and offer a "Show more content..." link. Once clicked, the full content is revealed, any other open articles would collapse, and a "Hide Content" link would be shown instead. This is the javascript code I am using. It is in  Prior to this, I also have the script src pointing to googleapi jQuery 1.9.1.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var slideHeight = 75;
$(".container").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.children(".wrap");
    var defHeight = $wrap.height();
    if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
        var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
        $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
        $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Click to Read More</a>");
        $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function (event) {
            var curHeight = $wrap.height();
            if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Close");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
            } else {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Click to Read More");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
</script>
<style>
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.gradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquery-slide/images/bg-gradient.png) repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.read-more {
    border-top: 4px double #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
}
.read-more a {
    padding-right: 22px;
    background: url(http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquery-slide/images/icon-arrow.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.read-more a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Header Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Nav Text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="copy">
      <div class="blPost">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="blTitle">Blog Post Title</h2>
          <div class="wrap">
            <div>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
              <p class="blArticle">Blog text goes here....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gradient"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you loading the file directly from your HD (`file://` URI) or via a webserver? What exactly does the URL look like that you use to load jQuery? The error means that jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tested both from my HD and the live server. either worked.

Comment: Try to add `http://` in front of the url in the script src. So it becomes `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Adding the http:// as you suggested didn't change anything, but I will keep that in anyway.

Comment: Post your HTML markup. That's definitely a problem with the jQuery library not being loaded.

Comment: “undefinedError $” ?? I doubt that's the error message. what browser are you using?

Comment: try adding the type attribute for the script `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Close the style tag before the script tag that adds jquery, maybe that helps.

Comment: @koala_dev — That's a chance to make a typo (making it more likely to cause problems than solve them) and is a waste of bytes.

Comment: @tyronetudehope — There is no style tag (of any kind) before that script tag.

Comment: I meant the link tag, I don't think either would be the problem in any case.

Comment: @tyronetudehope — `<link>` is an empty element. The end tag must be omitted in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/ijaSEPA/1/edit?html,output) the error message you report getting.

However, the code won't appear to run because you are looping over every element that is a member of the `container` class before you've added any such elements to the document.

Move the `<script>` so it appears just before `</body>` or wrap your code in a function that you pass to `jQuery(document).ready(your_function)`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has submitted responses. Quentin's answer has resolved my issue. Again, many thanks!